# error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have created an android application in which I have used android date picker. While submitting form in my application I am getting date in this format "18-2-2021" and I want to format this date in "18-Feb-2021" format. I don't want to force my user to update application so I want to format date in my c# web service code.

I am trying to format date using below code but I am getting "**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**".

```
DateTime requestRaisedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(ApplicationID.REQUEST_RAISED_DATE, "dd-MM-yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `18-2-2021` you need to allow single-digit months: `dd-M-yyyy`:

```
DateTime requestRaisedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(ApplicationID.REQUEST_RAISED_DATE, "dd-M-yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This allows `18-2-2021` and also `18-02-2021`.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#month-m-format-specifier

Comment: Thanks for your response. what will happen if I receive 25-10-2021 from mobile application because that time the month value is in two digit

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime requestRaisedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(ApplicationID.REQUEST_RAISED_DATE, "dd-M-yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Use Single M for single-digit month. It will support 10, 11,12 by default. So, don't worry